# Sharepoint 365 - API Updating List Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, ajax

I am trying to update a List Item in Sharepoint using the Rest API but am getting the following error:

```
The type of data at position 0 is different than the one expected.
```

Here is my code. The type is correct, the id is correct. The field i'm updating is

```
var string = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Presales_x0020_StagingListItem' }, '" + stagename + "': 'True'}";
        var id = getParameterByName('id');


$.ajax({
            url: "https://myurl.sharepoint.com/sites/EUBIEPresales/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Presales Staging')/items(" + id.toString() + ")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(string),
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");

            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Failure");
            }
        });
```

A couple of things:

- The Auth token is correct.
- The Id of the list item is correct
- The field i'm updating is a choice field

I think it's to do with the type i'm passing in, but I think it's correct. When I do a get I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xml:base="https://bicusa.sharepoint.com/sites/EUBIEPresales/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:etag="&quot;1&quot;">
<id>8fee51a1-1f5d-47c9-b1dd-d3a347faf1b1</id>
<category term="SP.Data.Presales_x0020_StagingListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/RoleAssignments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="RoleAssignments" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/RoleAssignments" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Activities" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Activities" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/Activities" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AttachmentFiles" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AttachmentFiles" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/AttachmentFiles" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContentType" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContentType" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/ContentType" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/GetDlpPolicyTip" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="GetDlpPolicyTip" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/GetDlpPolicyTip" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesAsHtml" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesAsHtml" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/FieldValuesAsHtml" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesAsText" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesAsText" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/FieldValuesAsText" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FieldValuesForEdit" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="FieldValuesForEdit" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/FieldValuesForEdit" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/File" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="File" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/File" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Folder" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Folder" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/Folder" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ParentList" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ParentList" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/ParentList" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Properties" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Properties" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/Properties" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Versions" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Versions" href="Web/Lists(guid'1364b153-851b-4897-ba61-f8daa59a7bde')/Items(5)/Versions" />
<title />
<updated>2017-08-31T08:08:10Z</updated>
<author>
    <name />
</author>
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:Id>
        <d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUri m:null="true" />
        <d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl></d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl>
        <d:ContentTypeId>0x0100C2F8BEC6D3FA244D8B1E7352DD885A0F</d:ContentTypeId>
        <d:Title>Test</d:Title>
        <d:Analyse_Goal_Pain_Points m:null="true" />
        <d:Analyse_Goal_Tech_Info m:null="true" />
        <d:Analyse_Goal_Deploy_Info m:null="true" />
        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:ID>
        <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-06-28T13:34:37Z</d:Modified>
        <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-06-28T13:34:37Z</d:Created>
        <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">18</d:AuthorId>
        <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">18</d:EditorId>
        <d:OData__UIVersionString>1.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
        <d:Attachments m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Attachments>
        <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">7f0e4060-c23c-457e-bee1-b904f058f8a2</d:GUID>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

Any pointers as to where I think I should look? When I create new list items, I pass in the same type and they work, so i'm not really sure where to look?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `JSON.stringify` an object instead of a string, like that :

```
JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Presales_x0020_StagingListItem' }, [stagename]: 'True'});
```

Comment: It's a good point, but hasn't resolved the issue. It's got to do with the Content Type but I can't see what content type "0x0100C2F8BEC6D3FA244D8B1E7352DD885A0F" is?

Comment: Well you don't need to specify the ContentType as you are using `__metadata`.  I don't know if it can help but my header looks like this : `headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE", "If-Match": "*" }`